# Qmake giving me error

Tags: c++, qt, short, qstring

I'm trying to convert a `string` into a `short` int  by using:

```
short tempS = QString("%1").arg(arguement);
```

where argument is a `QString`.
however I'm getting the error:

> crosses initialization of `short int tempS`

Answer (score 1):

There is a method toShort() in the QString class ([doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toShort)):

```
short tempS = arguement.toShort();
```

As shown in the doc, two arguments can be specified: a reference to a boolean to check if the conversion succeeded, and the base if you want anything else than 10.